How to read the instance "object type" in geometry node?
Is it possible to read the object type of the instance? For example this user would like to know if the instance are empties type object or regular objects
Using b4.2
Bests


You are showing two custom node groups there. What are they? Where are they from? What is inside of them?

Nothing, it's just an example of what the user is looking to have as a result

In my opinion, what he want is not possible yet

Who is he? Are you talking of yourself in the third person or for whom are you asking this question?

Theoretically you can get close to something like that, however there is a problem: my workaround mainly works with Meshes, Point Clouds and Curves because there we have the Domain Size node which we can use to determine if there is any kind of geometry in any of those domains.
The problem is, any mesh or curve object in Blender can have all its vertices or control points deleted in Edit Mode and would still be the same object type as before, but there is no more geometry which would be counted in the Domain Size node so they would appear as an Empty object.
Anyway, so much for the shortcomings of the following setup. What I basically do is using three Domain Size nodes, one set to Mesh, one to Point Cloud and one to Curve. The Point Count output is plugged into a Switch node. Each value greater than 0 will be interpreted as "True", and each object type should have a Point Count of 1 or more if it is not empty. To make sure this works even if the Object Info node is set to As Instance, I put a Realize Instances node in front of the Domain Size nodes. This makes the result factually incorrect, since Blender treats instances not as mesh, curve or other objects. But let's say this test is made to check for the "original" object type.
By giving each "True" result a specific integer value with a Switch node and combining them together, the end of the chain should result in an integer value that shows which object type is plugged in at the beginning. This integer value I use in an Index Switch node set to String to output the object type as string (which will then be used in the final output).

Now to check whether an instance is an empty or not, I simply add the three Point Count outputs of the different Domain Size nodes together. If any of them has ad least a single point, the object is not an Empty (but here the problem mentioned in the beginning is relevant that there is no difference between a "real" empty or any other object that simply has no geometry).

In the end I thought it might be interesting if an object is instanced or not in general (because as mentioned when checking the object type, even if the "original" would be for example a mesh, Blender treats it differently if it is instanced. Since the Domain Size node also has an Instance Count, whenever this is greather than 0 this means the object is instanced.

Altogether I combined all these strings and converted them so that I have a readable output of the result:

If I would now plug different objects in there, the text will show what type of object it is and if it is an Empty (kind of redundant since this is anwered with the first check) and if it is an instanced object (the Curve is instanced in this example):

All in all I've made four different custom node groups out of that: one that creates all the text as shown before, another one that just outputs the object type as string like in the question, another one that just outputs a boolean value "True" or "False" if the instance is an Empty (no matter if it is really an instance at all though) like in the question, and the fourth is an extension of the simple object type group, which apart from a string for the type also outputs a boolean value if the object is instanced or not.

//EDIT: Now that I was reminded that the original question was asking to do this with a collection of objects, I've created another nodetree. It uses the "Object Type" custom nodegroup of the other nodetree.
Basically I plug the collection into a Repeat Zone where the Instance Count of a Domain Size determines the number of Iterations. Then on each step a "counter" is increased by 1 and compared to the indices of the instances. A Split Instances node selects the instance object where the index is equal to the current counter value.
From this now single object I determine the typ with my previously created "Object Type" custom nodegroup and put out the string, I also read the position of the current instance and move it a little bit so that it is placed next to the object.
This can certainly be made prettier and maybe more convenient but I think it is something to start from. I ignored the "Is Instance Empty" nodegroup in this setup because an Empty will be written there in plain text so this should be good enough as base.



Hi Gordon
Thanks for your answer and your wonderful explanations! How would your system react if the object given was not a single object, but a collection of instances? Such as shown in the example image provided in the original post

@Fox Actually it will not react so well... if the collection would hold empties, meshes and curves, it would show the collection as containing a curve object (since all switches would be true and "Curve" is simply the last entry in this setup) and it would not show that there is an empty because the sum of all elements is not empty. Sorry, I did not bear in mind that there is a collection plugged in (since the question's singular phrasing "Is it possible to read the object type of the instance?" kept me thinking of trying to determine it for a single object. Guess this answer is useless then.

@Fox Okay, now I've added a version for collections at the end of the answer which is based on the solution for individual objects. The file is also updated, there is a new Geometry Nodes setup "Object Type Collection", but the old one which I named "Object Type Single" is still in there to choose from the modifier menu as well.
